# How to collapsed child item from list item in React Virtualized

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have some huge list and rendering using React Virtualized, but i am getting stuck. In the list item there is any child and parent item. so the child will be hiding before clicked the parent to collapsed the child.

Expectation:
Render all parent or item with no child, and when clicked the parent will collapsed the child component.

Here is the example code, with this code the child item will redereed with display none. so the bottom of parent there is element but doesn't appear make some white space.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { AutoSizer, List } from 'react-virtualized'

export default class AddressComponent extends Component {

  state = {
    data: [
      { 'number': 001, 'name': 'Musibah', 'postcode': 12345, 'parent': null, visibility: true },
      { 'number': 002, 'name': 'Musibah', 'postcode': 12345, 'parent': 001, visibility: false },
      { 'number': 003, 'name': 'Musibah', 'postcode': 12345, 'parent': 002, visibility: false },
      { 'number': 004, 'name': 'Musibah', 'postcode': 12345, 'parent': null, visibility: true },
      { 'number': 005, 'name': 'Musibah', 'postcode': 12345, 'parent': 004, visibility: false },
      { 'number': 006, 'name': 'Musibah', 'postcode': 12345, 'parent': null, visibility: true },
    ]
  }

  collapse = (index) => {
    this.setState((prev) => {
      let item = {};
      if (prev.data[index].visibility) {
        for (let i in prev.data) {
          if (prev.data[i].parent === prev.data[index].number) {
            prev.data[i].visibility = true;
          }
        }
      }
      return item;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <AutoSizer>
          {({ width, height }) => {
            <List
              rowCount={this.state.data.length}
              width={width}
              height={height}
              rowHeight={60}
              rowRenderer={({ key, index, styke }) => {
                return (
                  <li
                    key={key}
                    style={{
                      ...styke,
                      display: this.state.data[index].visibility ? 'block' : 'none'
                    }}
                  >
                    <button onClick={() => this.collapse(index)}>Show Child</button>
                    <p>{this.state.data[index].name} <span><br />{this.state.data[index].postcode}</span></p>
                  </li>
                );
              }}
            />
          }}
        </AutoSizer>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it would be great if you share some of your code to understand the problem.

Comment: i have added the sample code, similar like that

Comment: i solve it with only render visibility item. but now my problem is in on click. sometime is not working